# Android - How to display another overlay in onTap action of another overlay

Tags: java, android, overlay, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I am using MapView to display some polygons (zones) as Overlays on the canvas. I extended the class Overlay and now would like to implement the onTap method. After user taps on one of these zones another overlay should be displayed. I would like to define the layout of this overlay as a normal XML layout and than just inflate it and display.

I have already looked on one example called android-mapviewballoons, but it uses itemized overlays which take an Drawable resource and display it on the mapview. This drawable can than be taped. In my case I want my zone (polygon) to be the clickable resource. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Implement `onTap()` in your `Overlay` and confirm you are getting control when you want to.

Step #2: Adjust your existing layout such that the `MapView` is in a container that supports Z-axis ordering, like a `RelativeLayout`

Step #3: In `onTap()`, add another child to the container (and, eventually, get rid of that child, when appropriate)

[Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/EvenNooerYawk) from one of my books demonstrating this with an `ItemizedOverlay`, but there should be no significant difference for using the technique with a regular `Overlay`.